# Adding id attribute to FormControl element or parent angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to add an id attribute to the first invalid form control on form submission using angular reactive forms.

Here is what i currently have in my component:

```
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.invalid) {
      this.scrollToError();
    } else {
      this.submitted.emit(this.form.value);
    }
  }


  private scrollToError() {
    for (const prop in this.form.controls) {
      if (this.form.controls[prop].errors) {
        const control = this.form.get(prop);
        if (control.invalid) {
          control.parent.setAttribute('id', 'error') <=== Here is the issue
          console.log(control);
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

How can I get the element itself and add the id attribute?

Thanks

Comment: Could you explain what you want to achieve with this? Maybe there is a better approach

Comment: Im going to then use the id attribute (that is added to the first invalid form control) to scroll to but i need that element to have the id first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand, that you want to scroll to the first error element. Try

```
scrollToFirstError() {
  const firstElementWithError = document.querySelector('.ng-invalid');

  if (firstElementWithError) {
    firstElementWithError.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }
}
```

Comment: This is nice but because the whole form is invalid this also has the 'ng-invalid' class so it scrolls to the top of the page/form

Comment: After all I only want to say adding id just to be able to use the id query selector is like shooting from behind into an eye. Please check w3schools for example (https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp, https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) to find a good selector for you. I also could think about a selector like `querySelector('mat-form-field.ng-invalid')` or `querySelector('.ng-invalid[formControlName]')`